# Reading a large text file using BufferedReader, how badly does printing each line slow down the process?

Tags: java, performance, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I created a program to read a very large text file (2.5 GB), and re-write each line to a new text file formatted how I would like it to be. All is going well, but when I wrote it, I put a little 'println' where it reads the line for testing purposes, to see if it was working properly. All went well so I started it and went away from the computer, came back 3 hours later and saw that I had left the debug message there. My question is, how badly is this slowing me down if I'm reading/writing approximately 46,000,000 lines? Would it be wise to stop it this far in to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

well, I'd guess this would roughly double the ETA since you're basically creating another copy of the file in your log ;-)

Check how far you've got - then think about killing the process....

Answer (score 0):

Extra cost of "debug" `println` is very platform dependent.

If your `PrintStream` is routed to console you could be slowed down by extra processing related to console. On Windows default console is incredibly slow, on Linux to so much.

In addition, if you are using `System.out`/`System.err` your `PrintStream` would be configured to flush after each `println` adding extra overhead.

3 hours to process 2.5 GiB out of disk is very slow. So either your code doing is something complex and extra debug line has litle impact on overall performance, or you are on Windows writing to default console (in later case debug `println` is a huge problem).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things responsible for the entire process -

1. CPU
2. IO device

Initially, When you copy the lines from one file to another, there is no IO device involved in the process (Since you were not printing any line). So, There is no waiting time for the CPU. Hence, The process got completed in lesser time.

When you introduced the **println** statement, For each line CPU reads from the first file, it has to send that line to IO device for printing. After sending the line to IO Device, CPU has to wait for it to complete the job. Once IO device completes the printing, the CPU then continue the process and paste that line in the second file. This process will be continued until all the lines in the first file copied to the second file.

So, for every line in the file, CPU has to wait for a certain amount of time. This is the first reason for the increase in the processing time. Second, IO printing creates another copy of the file. So, Now you are creating 2 copies instead of one.

> 46,000,000 lines?

```
Let's take the time taken by each operation in the process is 1 microsecond.Initially - 

Time took by CPU to copy a line = 1 microsecond
Time took by CPU to paste a line = 1 microsecond
Total time for copying 46,000,000 lines = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec
Total time for pasting 46,000,000 lines = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec
Total time of the entire process = 92 sec.
```

**Println Introduced**

```
Time took by CPU to copy a line = 1 microsecond
Time took by IO to paste a line = 1 microsecond
Time took by CPU to paste a line = 1 microsecond
Waiting time of CPU for every line = 1 microsecond

Total time taken by CPU for copying 46,000,000 lines = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec
Total time taken by IO for copying 46,000,000 lines = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec
Waiting time of CPU = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec
Total time by CPU for pasting 46,000,000 lines = 46,000,000 microsecond = 46 sec

Total time of the entire process = 184 sec.
```

Hope this answers your query!